# AWS EventBridge Rule Event Pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

this is the architecture that I have now.

Lambda (Put events to event bus) -> Event Bridge -> Event bus in another AWS account

Right now, lambda is putting events using `putEvents` API to `Event Bridge`. Now I want to send these events to another Event bus but in a different AWS account. I'm wondering what kind of event pattern should I need to create for the rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event pattern does not change. But the target changes. In your case, to forward events to different account you have to choose special target for that:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Marcin could you help me out with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75976403/implementing-event-bridge-rule-onto-aws-cdk