# Implementing event bridge rule onto aws CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I am new to AWS CDK and have a issue implementing what I was able to implement on the AWS console successfully

this is the event rule that I have setup {

```
"$or": [{
      "detail.distance": [{
        "numeric": [">=", 0]
      }]
    }, {
      "detail.duration": [{
        "numeric": [">=", 0]
      }]
    }],
    "replay-name": [{
      "exists": true
    }]
    
  }
```

When I am trying to implement this in CDK
I could see the limitation it has with setting up event pattern

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_events/EventPattern.html

what i am trying:

```
cfn_rule = aws_events.CfnRule(
    self,
    id=f"{stack_id}-rule-to-invoke-lambda",
    name="rule-to-invoke-lambda",
    event_bus_name=event_bus.event_bus_name,
    event_pattern=aws_events.EventPattern(
        source=["mts-simulation"], #toDo Have to add the pattern but unable to design it 
    ),
    targets=[
        aws_events.CfnRule.TargetProperty(
            arn=lambda_function.function_arn, #coming in from function parameter
            id=f"{stack_id}-target-to-lambda-function",
            input_transformer=aws_events.CfnRule.InputTransformerProperty(
                input_template='{"uptime":"<detail-uptime>",'
                ' "distance": "<detail-distance>",'
                '"duration": "<detail-duration>","timestamp": "<timestamp>"}',
                input_paths_map={
                    "timestamp": "$.time",
                    "detail-uptime": "$.detail.system_uptime",
                    "detail-distance": "$.detail.distance",
                    "detail-duration": "$.detail.duration",
                    
                },
            ),
        )
    ],
)
```

This could be elementary but currently stuck with it.
Could anyone have bit of patient and help me out of it?

Edited after implementing the answer from Scott Hsieh:

Missing out on 2 things:

1. associating it to an exiting event bus
2. 

```
{
  "detail": {
    "replay-name": [{
      "exists": true
    }],
    "$or": [{
      "distance": [{
        "numeric": [">=", 0]
      }]
    }, {
      "duration": [{
        "numeric": [">=", 0]
      }]
    }]
  },
  "source": ["mts-simulation"]
}
```

this rule is failing because "replay-name" is flowing into a event outside detail part of the a json event.

for example:
event =

```
{ "field1":"value",
    "field2":"value",
    detail:{ "distance":"value",
    "duration":"value"
    }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Brief to AWS CDK Constructs

CfnRule is a L1 construct a.k.a CFN resources. In most cases you choose L2 constructs for your CDK application since built-in **L2 constructs are usually crafted with intention for most general scenarios**. You can also realize that using L1 constrcuts usually takes more effort regarding setting attributes than L2 constructs. For now, as a beginner, I would suggest you neglect L3 constructs at first, you come to meet up L3 when you are more advanced with CDK. For detail, you can read through this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_lib).

### Implementing an Event Rule with AWS CDK in Python

Back to your question, it looks like a case where an event will trigger a Lambda function and you want to manage this flow with CDK based on Python. As you can see from the documentation of [`EventPattern`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_events/EventPattern.html#aws_cdk.aws_events.EventPattern):

> **Important**: this class can only be used with a `Rule` class. In particular, do not use it with `CfnRule` class: your pattern will not be rendered correctly. In a `CfnRule` class, write the pattern as you normally would when directly writing CloudFormation.

With your intention, I believe the following snippet can fit your needs:

```py
.
.
import aws_cdk.aws_events as events
import aws_cdk.aws_events_targets as targets
.
.
.
"""
Python version: Python 3.11.2
CDK version: 2.73.0 (build 43e681e)
"""
rule = events.Rule(self, "rule",
    rule_name="rule-to-invoke-lambda",
    event_pattern=events.EventPattern(
        source=["mts-simulation"],
        detail={
            "$or": [
                {"distance": [{"numeric": [">=", 0]}]},
                {"duration": [{"numeric": [">=", 0]}]}
            ],
            "replay-name": [{"exists": True}]
        }
    )
)
rule.add_target(targets.LambdaFunction(lambda_function,
    event=events.RuleTargetInput.from_object({
            "uptime": events.EventField.from_path("$.detail.system_uptime"),
            "distance": events.EventField.from_path("$.detail.distance"),
            "duration": events.EventField.from_path("$.detail.duration"),
            "timestamp": events.EventField.from_path("$.detail.time")
        })
))
```

### CloudFormation JSON Output

After synthesizing, your CFN JSON output will be similar as the following:

```json
"ruleF2C1DCDC": {
   "Type": "AWS::Events::Rule",
   "Properties": {
    "EventPattern": {
     "detail": {
      "$or": [
       {
        "distance": [
         {
          "numeric": [
           ">=",
           0
          ]
         }
        ]
       },
       {
        "duration": [
         {
          "numeric": [
           ">=",
           0
          ]
         }
        ]
       }
      ],
      "replay-name": [
       {
        "exists": true
       }
      ]
     },
     "source": [
      "mts-simulation"
     ]
    },
    "Name": "rule-to-invoke-lambda",
    "State": "ENABLED",
    "Targets": [
     {
      "Arn": {
       "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "LambdaFunctionBF21E41F",
        "Arn"
       ]
      },
      "Id": "Target0",
      "InputTransformer": {
       "InputPathsMap": {
        "detail-system_uptime": "$.detail.system_uptime",
        "detail-distance": "$.detail.distance",
        "detail-duration": "$.detail.duration",
        "detail-time": "$.detail.time"
       },
       "InputTemplate": "{\"uptime\":<detail-system_uptime>,\"distance\":<detail-distance>,\"duration\":<detail-duration>,\"timestamp\":<detail-time>}"
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   "Metadata": {
    "aws:cdk:path": "EventLambdaStack/rule/Resource"
   }
  }
```

### Feedback

In the future when managing AWS infrastructure with CDK, examples in CDK documentation would be valuable since in some cases, configuration in CloudFormation and setting via CDK APIs can differ a bit much. You can use the minimal snippet to check the difference of the L2 APIs and CFN configuration. In the end, try to figure out what L2 components are crafted for Amazon EventBridge and its available targets in CDK. Good luck on your CDK journey.

Comment: One question that i have is, how do we associate with the event bus of our?

Comment: I can share some hints. 1. There is an argument named `event_bus` in Class `Rule`. 2. An event bus can be referenced from an existing resource or created by the CDK application. 3. Check what type (class) the argument accepts.

Comment: I am exploring it event_bus (Optional[IEventBus]). 
with in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_events/RuleProps.html
But the class taken in type protocol.
Bit difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is great. But didn't seem to figure that out for my requirement.
Here is what worked out for me:

```
cfn_rule = aws_events.CfnRule(
            self,
            id=f"{stack_id}-invoke-lambda-read-file",
            name="rule-to-invoke-lambda-read-file",
            event_bus_name=event_bus.event_bus_name,
            event_pattern={"$or":[{"detail.distance":[{"numeric":[">=",0]}]},{"detail.duration":[{"numeric":[">=",0]}]}],"replay-name":[{"exists":True}]},
            targets=[
                aws_events.CfnRule.TargetProperty(
                    arn=lambda_function.function_arn,
                    id=f"{stack_id}-invoke-lambda-read-file",
```

as you could see I am passing event_patter as an dictionary explicitly.

hope it helps.